# How to debug init file which cause "emacs24.4 --daemon" doesn't return to shell?

Tags: linux, emacs, elisp, emacs24

Just got emacs24.4 compiled and try to run it in daemon mode.

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

In terminal:
When I run it with "emacs -Q --daemon" everything works fine. But when I run it with "emacs --daemon", it doesn't return to shell (emacs24.3 works fine).

Is there any easy way to debug what's wrong in the init file which works fine for 24.3 but not 24.4?

Comment: `strace` it -- what's it doing?  Also, double check the changelog in case this is by design

Comment: try `emacs --daemon --debug-init`

Answer (score 0):

*Recursively bisect your init file, to find out what the culprit code is.* You can do this by commenting out 1/2 of it, then 3/4 of it, then 7/8, then 15/16,... IOW, a binary search - it is very quick.

You can use command `comment-region` to comment or (with `C-u`) to uncomment the region.  (I bind it to `C-x C-;`.)

Then **remember this answer.** It applies to **any** problem introduced by your init file.

Everything in your question that has to do with "Emacs 24.4" and "daemon" and "shell" only becomes relevant (if it is) after you have narrowed things down to find just what code is responsible for introducing the bad behavior.Once you do that, if the solution to what remains is not obvious, then please post another (new) question here that covers the relevant info, whether it be Emacs 24.4, shell, daemon, or whatever.